# AsyncTask retrieve data from onPostExecute

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, download

I wrote a little class to download data from an URL.

The downloader class :

```
public class HTTPHelper extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private OnHTTPCompleted listener;

    HTTPHelper(OnHTTPCompleted l){
        listener = l;
    }

    private String readStream(InputStream is) {
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int i = is.read();
            while (i != -1) {
                bo.write(i);
                i = is.read();
            }
            return bo.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "";
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            try {
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                return readStream(in);
            } finally {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        try {
            listener.onHttpCompleted(s);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The interface class:

```
public interface OnHTTPCompleted {
    void onHttpCompleted(Object o);
}
```

We want the download to be asynchronous, therefore we decided to use `AsyncTask`. We want to return data from the HTTP class after the download is completed, BUT : Without updating UI elements directly in the `onPostExecute` method.

We just want to **return the raw data** without further processing.
All other solutions we were able to find directly used the downloaded data in the `onPostExecute` method to update some UI elements etc.

Also worth mentioning : `task.get()` is not an option because it is blocking the main thread.

Comment: What is the problem, exactly? That is, how exactly is your posted code not working as you want?

Comment: @MikeM. The downloader does work, however AsyncTask is a closed system and we are unable to retrieve any results out of the AsyncTask class. We are only able to insert code with an interface. Basically we can put data into the AsyncTask class but not get any data out of it. (I hope you can follow along)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "We are only able to insert code with an interface." The interface is how you would get the result in the calling object. The `onHttpCompleted()` method will be run from `onPostExecute()`, and the `Object o` parameter will be the data. It might better illustrate your issue if you show us how you're creating and executing the `AsyncTask`, and explain the problems you're having in that context.

Comment: Who/what is going to be using this data?  The `onPostExecute()` method is the natural place to be using the data from your async call, because it itself gets called once that task is complete.

Comment: Yes, we are aware of that but this requires us to interact with UI elements in a class which should be isolated from that. The Helper should ONLY download data and return it and the update/usage of the data should be performed in a separate class. So to our understanding it would be a design problem to interact with the UI in the downloader class. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: It's still unclear what the problem is. Nothing about an `AsyncTask` mandates interacting with the UI at all. However, If you do want to update the UI with the resulting data, then that would be done in the interface implementation in the calling object, not in the `AsyncTask`.

Comment: I have read the question several times and the comments as well but failed to understand what do you want?. `onPostExcecute()` does not require you to interact with the UI. it's just called after the task completes, you have the freedom to interact or not !!

Comment: I think what he is referring to is no inherit functionality flaw but it just seems to go against Java encapsulation according to the OOP principles, which I do agree with @MikeM.

Comment: @virhonestum Ah, that very well may be what they mean, but they didn't really make that clear in the question. The emphasis there seems to be on not processing the data before delivering it, what with the bolded text, and the mention of the `get()` method.

Comment: Yeah @virhonestum thats exactly what I meant. So what would be the best way to solve this now that the question is clear?

Comment: TBH, if that is what you intended, the question itself is still not clear. Please [edit] it to emphasize what you actually mean.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I have understood your problem based on the question and the comments under the question, you are trying to use the `AsyncTask` as a library function which will do the job of downloading for you. You do not want to handle any further processing with the downloaded material inside the `AsyncTask`. You want to process them later in the calling class which is fine.

If I have understood correctly, then you are almost there. You just have to change some declaration in your `AsyncTask`. Let me re-write your `AsyncTask` here with some edit in it.

```
public class HTTPHelper extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ByteArrayOutputStream> {

    private OnHTTPCompleted listener;

    HTTPHelper(OnHTTPCompleted l){
        listener = l;
    }

    private ByteArrayOutputStream readStream(InputStream is) {
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int i = is.read();
            while (i != -1) {
                bo.write(i);
                i = is.read();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected ByteArrayOutputStream doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            try {
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                return readStream(in);
            } finally {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ByteArrayOutputStream s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        try {
            listener.onHttpCompleted(s);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

As you have wanted to return the raw data without further processing, you had to return the `ByteArrayOutputStream` to the calling UI thread without converting it to `String` object. Hope that helps!

Comment: I think you missed the final comments below the question. It seems this is not what the OP is talking about.